# Iterative program for sum of list in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, iteration

Hey I am a little bit confused over prolog recursion and iteration. I am giving code for sum of a list in recursion and iteration respectively and want to know if each of them is correct or not...

```
add_r([],0).   
add_r([H|T],X) :- add_r(T,X1),X is H + X1.

add_i(List,Sum) :- add_i(List,0,Sum).   
add_i([H|T],I,Sum) :- I1 is I + H , add_i(T,I1,Sum).   
add_i([], I1, I1).
```

here add_r is recursive program and add_i is iterative (according to me)...I may be wrong.Here "I" is used for iteration control.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the terminology of Abelson & Sussman (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs) you are quite correct.

In this case "iterative" means the state of the process is fully described by just a few variables and "recursive" means the number of variables grows with each call. Also, a "recursive" process has 2 stages: grow and reduction and when it grows it leaves "choice-points" etc (all the differences are described in SICP).

In Prolog the term "tail recursion" is used more often than "iterative" in regard to your second example.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, Prolog *doesn't* allow iteration, because variables are 'write once' (kind of...).

Both predicates are recursive, and seem correct to me.

The difference between them it's that add_i is *tail recursive* (the recursive call appears as last), and thus the compiler can optimize it (see last call optimization, or [Tail Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)), replacing the recursive call *with a jump*, thus avoiding the linear stack space required by add_r .